# Method not launching

Tags: c#, methods

I just started c#, thank you all for your patience.  I am following a course on udemy and i dont understand why my method is not launching.

Here is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Exercise1()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 to 10: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var number = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        if (number >= 1 && number <= 10)
            Console.WriteLine("Valid");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          Exercise1();  // my method is not appearing in intelisense, what am i doing wrong?
    }
}
```

Comment: `Exercise1` is not a static method. You can not call non-static method from a static method. So you need to make `Exercise1` a static method by doing `public static void Exercise1()`

Comment: If you don't want `Exercise1()` to be static then you need to call it in Main by creating an instance of Program class. `Program p = new Program(); p.Exercise1();`

Answer (score 4):

Just mark the method as `static`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Exercise1()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 to 10: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var number = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        if (number >= 1 && number <= 10)
            Console.WriteLine("Valid");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          Exercise1(); 
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Main` is `static`, meaning it doesn't need an instance of `Program` to run. If you want `Main` to call other methods in `Program`, those methods also need to be `static`.

The only other way to do it would be this:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Exercise1()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 to 10: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var number = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        if (number >= 1 && number <= 10)
            Console.WriteLine("Valid");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          var prog = new Program();
          prog.Exercise1(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, now could you tell me why when i launch that method, it takes the readline command but does not print  my if/else statement?

Comment: Try adding a `Console.ReadKey()` at the end, I'm guessing the program outputs the Valid or Invalid and then quits the program.

Comment: i absolutely need to create an instance of program in order to launch the method in it?

Comment: No, you can mark it as `static` as in the first example to call it without creating an instance.